# Pulling data out of a nested json response

Tags: javascript, json, axios

So I am making a request to the new twitch API and I'm having trouble getting the data from the response.

```
{  
   data:[  
      {  
         id:'28793268096',
         user_id:'71092938',
         game_id:'488552',
         community_ids:[  

         ],
         type:'live',
         title:'NEW EVENT POG ~ twitter.com/xqc',
         viewer_count:9143,
         started_at:'2018-05-22T17:09:12Z',
         language:'en',
         thumbnail_url:'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_xqcow-{width}x{height}.jpg'
      },
      {  
         id:'28792267216',
         user_id:'23220337',
         game_id:'488552',
         community_ids:[  
            Array
         ],
         type:'live',
         title:'Overwatch Ranked Season 2 Episode 16: Panic! On The Payload | !charity | !patch',
         viewer_count:2332,
         started_at:'2018-05-22T15:25:47Z',
         language:'en',
         thumbnail_url:'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_emongg-{width}x{height}.jpg'
      }
   ],
   pagination:{  
      cursor:'eyJiIjpudWxsLCJhIjp7Ik9mZnNldCI6Mn19'
   }
}
```

Using the code below I'm not getting any data from the array.

```
var reply = axios.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?game_id=488552&type=live&first=2&language=en')
    .then(function(response){
        var datas = response.data;
        //console.log(datas);
        for(var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
            var cube = datas[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < cube.length; j++) {
                msg.reply(cube.id);
            }
        }
}).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i solved the problem. I just appended another .data on the response and it worked fine

Comment: Isn't what you're doing causing you to fire `msg.reply(cube.id);` once for every property of the 'cube' object? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

The values contained within the `data` array are objects, and thus, do not have a `length` property. So when you are working on `cube.length`, the expression is `false` and not running `msg.reply(cube.id)`. Once you set `cube` you should be working on it directly.

Without knowing what you're attempting to do, I cannot provide much more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a modern browser with javascript ES6 this should work. The "cube" objects are just children of the data array, so you just forEach over the array and grab the ids.

```
response.data.forEach((el, i) => {
  msg.reply(el.id);
});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tr7zmrw7/1/

if you want a less modern way, you can do:

```
for(var i in response.data){
  msg.reply(response.data[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Looks like it's because you aren't sending an authorization token

Here's your example simplified. You can see it's hitting the error block and showing:

```
{
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "status": 401,
  "message": "Must provide a valid Client-ID or OAuth token"
}
```

```js
var reply = axios.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?game_id=488552&type=live&first=2&language=en')
    .then(function(response){

    console.log(response)
    
}).catch((error) => {

  console.log('got error')
  console.log(error.response.data);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't loop through an object like that.

You can msg.reply the whole object:

```
var reply = axios.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?game_id=488552&type=live&first=2&language=en')
    .then(function(response){
        var datas = response.data;
        //console.log(datas);
        for(var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
            msg.reply(datas[i]);
        }
}).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
```

Or loop through the object like:

```
var reply = axios.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?game_id=488552&type=live&first=2&language=en')
        .then(function(response){
            var datas = response.data;
        for(var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
            for (var key in datas[i]) {
                if (!datas[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
                var obj = datas[key];
                for (var prop in obj) {
                    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
                    console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
                }
            }
        }
    }).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
```